# How to calculate AWS S3 CP download time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, time, aws-cli

I want to calculate the amount of time elapsed during a download with `aws s3 cp` command.
When using the command

`time aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mypath/myfile` .

I cannot get the download time correctly:

```
time aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mypath/myfile . 

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

while during the download I have temporary info:

```
Completed 256.0 KiB/1.6 MiB (15.0 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
```

I do not have the total amount of time elapsed.

Comment: Did the command actually download any files? Did `mypath` include the name of a file, or was it just a directory name?

Comment: yes it downloads the file locally, sorry was un clear, updated to `s3://mybucket/mypath/myfile`

Comment: That is quite strange! On what computer are you running the command (eg on an EC2 instance or your own computer)? Worst case, you could put the commands in a script file, then time how long it takes to run the script.